# Slow Solr query response time for long queries

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have a single-core [1], non-replicating Solr index containing ~40 million documents. Each document has two fields, one stored, the other not. I search on the non-stored field, the stored field being my result.

Response times from this index are around 8 seconds. Something to note is that I'm not making what I consider the typical full-text query. Each query contains dozens of OR terms. I expected this to be slow, but not quite as slow as it is.

Something I notice is that Solr is using only a couple of hundred MBs of the 7GBs its JVM has available. It can't be keeping much of the index in memory. Which leads to my question: is there a way to configure solr such that it is forced to maintain much (or at least more) of its index in RAM?

[1] Sharding introduces a problem for me. Relative scores are extremely important in my application of Solr. Shard-local scoring means the more shards I have, the less accurate scores become.

More information in response to comments:

Here's the field type definition for the field I search on:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and here's an example query:

```
(Carberry J 2008 Toward a Unified Theory of High-Energy Metaphysics Silly String Theory Journal of Psychoceramics 5 11 1 3)
```

This will take around 10s to respond, whereas a query with fewer ORed terms, such as (Carberry 2008), will return in ~100ms.

Comment: Please provide some more info - an example query and what are the fields types, what tokenization is applied (any)?

Comment: @kpentchev I've added some info on the schema and an example query.

Comment: Should also mention that I tried to put the index on a ramfs mount. Unfortunately it increased response times by 2s!

Comment: Have you perhaps enabled highlighting? Is lazy loading of fields enabled in solrconfig.xml? How big are the retrieved fields?

Comment: Lazy field loading is enabled. However, since I only have two fields, the search field which is not stored, and a stored field which is the result I want, doubt that will make much of an affect either way.

Highlighting is not configured, and in fact query debug output shows that nearly all of the time is spent in the query component, with 0 time in pretty much everything else. (A few ms for the debug component, too.)

Comment: I wonder if the large number of terms is just too much to ask of Lucene / Solr?

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your last question. The retrieved fields have an average length of about 20 characters.

Comment: What I find very strange is that the query with fewer ORed terms actually runs slower that the one with more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found and solved the problem I had.

Turns out that many of my documents, since they are made up of bibliographic metadata, contain some very common words on top of the usual English stop words. Such words include 'journal' and 'proceedings'. Further, because my documents contain author names, often including initials, many of them contained indexed single-letter terms. If any of these were included as a query term, response time would go up an order of magnitude.

My solution was to simply filter out these common terms using a StopFilter and LengthFilter, like so:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
```

Comment: Actually to both query and index filters, since there's no point indexing something that will never be queried for. Though I'd guess that adding the above to only a query filter would have the same effect. (I'm assuming though that the issue is in querying for common short terms, rather than any issue introduced by the structure or size or some other feature of an index for documents containing many similar short terms.)